# Update Null Value In mysql

Tags: mysql, null

Hello I want to update field value where Field have NULL value 
i am using

```
UPDATE video
SET    like = 0
WHERE  like IS NULL;
```

but it's not working . can any one help me ?

Comment: maybe `like` is not `NULL`. might be `empty string` Try this instead : `..WHERE like  IS NULL OR  like  = '' `

Comment: What exactly do you mean that your query does not work?

Comment: Not working is not enough information. Are you getting any error ? I suppose you should have an error.

Comment: Also note that `like` is a reserved word. Enclose it by backtick while using

Answer (score 2):

`like` is a keyword in SQL. e.g. `where textcolumn like "%TEST%"`

So you'll have to escape it, if you're using it as a column name.

Try can this:

```
update video set `like` = 0 where `like` is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, May be your the value of like is empty string or a spacebar.

```
UPDATE video
SET    like = 0
WHERE  like IS NULL
OR like =''
OR like = ' ';
```